# $f,g \in L^2(0,\pi)$ show that $\int_0^\pi (f(x)-\sin(x))^2dx \leq 4/9$ and $\int_0^\pi (f(x)-\cos(x))^2dx \leq 1/9$ can not hold simultaneously

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Going for a proof by contradiction, lets assume both inequalities hold. It is clear that the statement can be re-written as $||f(x) - \sin(x)||_2 \leq \frac{2}{3}$ and $||f(x) - \cos(x)||_2 \leq \frac{1}{3}$. At this point, we can use Minkowski's inequality (given $f,g \in L^p(E)$, $||f+g||_p \leq ||f||_p + ||g||_p$), to get
$$\sqrt{\int_0^\pi |(f(x) - \cos(x)) + (f(x) - \sin(x))|^2 dx} \leq ||f(x) - \cos(x)||_2+||f(x) - \sin(x)||_2 \leq 1$$ Trying to expand the left hand side seems way too messy and circular. I am not sure how to proceed from here. It somehow seems like I am overcomplicating this problem.

I was also looking into Holder's inequality, but once again, having to compute $||(f(x) - \sin(x))(f(x)-\cos(x))||_1$ seems very messy.

Any hint/help is appreciated!

Comment: Hint: $\|\cos-\sin\| \leq \|f-\cos\| + \|f-\sin\|$.

Comment: ... Wow! this was so simple that I am kind of embarrassed for posting the question now. Thank you so much !!!